# Launch App in PortraitUpsideDown gives translation problems

Tags: iphone, translation, orientation, autorotate, portrait

I've got several images within my view. On rotation my images are being placed properly by means of a CGAffineTransformTranslate & Rotate.

However when I launch in PortraitUpsidedown a translation takes place which I defined wihin the

"-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration { " method.

This translation only has to take place on a orientation change with the device. How can I make sure that this translation doesn't happen on Launch?

EDIT:

Still got problems after your tip with implementing the viewWillAppear method.

Here is some code of my project.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        image1.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( image1.transform, -65.0, 255.0);
        image2.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( image2.transform, -65.0, 255.0);
    }
    else {

        image1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        image2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)isRotated{

    isRotated = FALSE;
}
```

But how do I implement the piece of code where I define

```
isRotated = TRUE;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Set a `BOOL` variable. Make it `YES` when the interface is what we required to use `CGAffineTransformTranslate` & rotate, or call the method from there to translate:

like:

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    // do something
```